# The Brauer group of the function field of a proper curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, brauer-groups

Let $X$ be a smooth proper geometrically connected curve over a number field $k$, and let $k(X)$ denote its field of rational functions, i.e., its function field. Then the (cohomological) Brauer group of $k(X)$ is $\mathrm{Br}(k(X)) = H^2(k(X),\bar{k}(X)^*)$.

In the paper *Transcendental Brauer-Manin obstruction on a pencil of elliptic curves* by Olivier Wittenberg, on page 2, for an elliptic curve $E$, he wrote

> It follows from the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence, Tsen's theorem and Hilbert's theorem $90$ that the inflation map $H^2(k,\bar{k}(E)^*) \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}(k(E))$ is an isomorphism.

I know the roles played by Hilbert 90 and Tsen's theorem in the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence
$$H^p(k,H^q(E_{\bar{k}},\mathbb{G}_m)) \implies H^{p+q}(E,\mathbb{G}_m),$$
but I can't find a suitable spectral sequence to derive the inflation map above. Could anyone suggest one?

Also, could we replace $E$ by a smooth proper curve of arbitrary genus (with a $k$-point, if necessary) over $k$?

Comment: @abx but what cohomology is $H^i(k(E)^*)$?

Comment: (edited comment) The spectral sequence is$$H^p(k,H^q(\bar{k}(E),\mathbb{G}_m)) \implies H^{p+q}(k(E),\mathbb{G}_m),$$and the inflation map comes from $E^{2,0}_2\rightarrow E^{2,0}_{\infty}\subset H^2$.

Comment: @abx I've worked it out as what you said, but I will need to show that $\mathrm{Pic}(\bar{k}(E)) = 0$ in order for the isomorphism to be true, since I'll need $E^{0,1} = E^{1,1} = 0$. But I don't see why. The function field of an elliptic curve with affine equation $f$ is given to be the fraction field of $k[X,Y]/(f)$, which is not necessarily a UFD and so it need not be zero.

Comment: The Picard group of a field is zero.

Comment: @abx I stupidly forgot that a field is a UFD, sorry about that.